Getting a formula based on a graph
I am trying to approximate the data into a formula, but I cannot understand the basis of the formula. Maybe you can help, thanks for the help!
>>>data graph<<<
Note: There are few points in final data, there the curve tends to infinity upwards

Based on an estimation of the 5 roots, I have found this rather satisfying $5$th degree polynomial :
$$y=a(x+2.5)(x+1.6)(x+0.3)(x-1.07)(x-2.3)$$
(where $a$ has no significant value until the scale on the $y$ axis is known).


This is exactly the function!
I have already implemented the approximation for the "Quintic function", but I seem to have errors in the implementation( Went to look for them. Thanks for your help!

Happy for the "good fit" ! Of course the solution is also "up to a horizontal  translation"...
